# Tkinter Strange Attribute Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new here! I've visited from time to time, but now I thought I'd join the community.

Background info: My program will randomly generate a password and will be able to save that password for the user in an sqlite3 database. The user will then be able to view and recall passwords later in a separate window.

Here's my code, I'm using frames for a login page and then table page:

```
class passwordViewer(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tkinter.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PVLoginPage, PVTable):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.passwordDB = sqlite3.connect('PDB.db')
        print("Database connected successfully.")

        self.showFrame("PVLoginPage")

    def getDB(self):
        return self.passwordDB
```

That's my controller. It creates a connection to the DB file and then there's a method to return the DB. I had some other methods but they're unimportant.

This is for my login page:

```
class PVLoginPage(tkinter.Frame):

    def userLogin(self, ID, password):
        try:
            passwordDB = self.controller.getDB()
            passwordDBQuery = passwordDB.cursor()
            print("Statement ran successfully.")
            passwordDBQuery.execute('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME="%s" AND PASSWORD="%s"' % (ID, password))
            if passwordDBQuery.fetchone() is not None:
                print("Logged in successfully.")
                self.controller.showFrame("PVTable")
            else:
                print("Authentication failed!")
        except IOError:
                print("Select statement could not execute!")
```

This executes just fine. It gets the DB object from the controller and it works perfectly.

This however (which is inside another frame class just underneath the login one):

```
    def LoadTable(self):
        try:
            passwordDB = self.controller.getDB()
            passwordDBQuery = passwordDB.cursor()
            #SQL Query Here.
        except IOError:
            print("Query failed!")
```

Throws this error:

```
return self.passwordDB
File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2095, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'passwordDB'
```

The constructor of the PVTable class runs LoadTable() when it initializes.

Sorry if I've over-posted here. I wanted to be concise but didn't want to lack detail or cause confusion as to what I am trying to achieve.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to say for sure without seeing your full code, but as a guess you are calling "LoadTable" in the `__init__` method, which runs before you make your database connection.

A quick fix would be to move the `self.passwordDB = sqlite3.connect('PDB.db')` line to the top of the method, before making the frames.